# Little endian representation of register value problem

Tags: assembly, gdb, endianness

I have the following line of assembly code:

```
mov rax,067FEh
```

When I examine the value of register rax with gdb during execution, I get:

```
(gdb) p/x $rax
$2 = 0x67fe
(gdb) p/t $rax
$3 = 110011111111110
```

However, my machine is a little Endian architecture, so I don't understand why the binary value in the register is 110011111111110 and not  11111110 01100111 with the lowest byte (fe) first?

Thanks

Comment: endianness comes to play when value is stored/loaded into memory, the register inside CPU has no endianness, `rax` is 64 bit register as whole. You may try to read through this answer (although for MIPS, it should help you understand your question, or you may try to ask me about particular thing): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555190/4271923

Comment: Thanks.
I don't quite understand that endianness does not apply to registers. For instance if I execute the following instruction:

mov rax,'ABCDEFGH'

and then check the value of the rax register, the bytes of the value 'ABCDEFGH' appear backwards both in hex and binary(with asc value of A at end) :

`(gdb) p/x $rax
$20 = 0x4847464544434241
(gdb) p/t $rax
$21 = 100100001000111010001100100010101000100010000110100001001000001`

Why does it display the bytes backwards as a result of this instruction(`mov rax,'ABCDEFGH'`) and not the instruction further above (`mov rax,067FEh`)?

Comment: that's extra use-case not covered by that answer. Generally `mov rax,'TEXT'` is bogus as there's no such instruction directly, only bit pattern (64/32) can be loaded into `rax` register. So some assemblers are trying to be helpful/convenient and translate the "text" into some bit pattern. For example NASM does this in reversed order, so if you write in source `mov rax,'hello'` `mov [mem_buffer],rax` storing that value into memory, the memory buffer will contain the text in human-expected order, starting with `'h'` as first byte (low 8 bits of `rax`). But that's extra feature of assembler.

Comment: If you use valid instruction, like `mov rax,0x123456789ABCDEF0`, then the top bits 60..63 contain the value "1" (0001), etc... in the order what humans treat as "high order digits" in that source string "1234...", those hexa digits end in the high order bits. How exactly the CPU physically stored registers is completely transparent to the asm programmer, it may even keep the bits shuffled and intermixed with other registers, but as long as programmer by addressing particular bit will receive the correct value, it's invisible to him. From programmers point of view `rax` is 64-bit, inseparable.

Comment: Here is NASM documentation describing this extra feature: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.3