# How does the 16 bit x86 registers store data?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

if I was to use:
mov ax, 0x0904

would it be stored with ah being 0x04 and al being 0x09 or would it be the other way around?

Comment: related [Is mars MIPS simulator Big or Little Endian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555190/4271923)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way around - AL will be 4, AH will be 9. H in AH stands for "high", L stands for "low".

x86 is a little endian machine though. If you store the same value in memory, say, at address 0x1000, the byte at 0x1000 will be 4 and the byte at 0x1001 will be 9.

On a side note, hex numbers 0x04 and 0x09 are 4 and 9, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. I was unsure if the little endian format applied to the registers too.

Comment: @Armature Endianness has no meaning in registers, only in memory. So no, registers are nor little-endian neither big-endian because they have no addresses.