# Alternative for sw MIPS instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

What is an alternative to save a word from register into RAM? 
For example i can explain lw command as lui, ori. How could be 4 Bytes stored into RAM without using sw?

Comment: No you can't. `lw` is not the same as `lui` and `ori`. You are probably thinking of `la`.

Comment: Why not? lw loads one word to register. Is not same, but it's possible to do the same with lui and ori. And i'm looking for same instructions set, that could exchange sw.

Comment: No you can not do the same with `lui` and `ori`. `lw` accesses memory, the alternatives don't. You can only use `lui/ori` to load a known compile-time constant. `lw` reads memory. Tell me, how do you write for example `lw $a0, ($t0)` using `lui/ori`?

Comment: _"How could be 4 Bytes stored into RAM without using sw?"_ By using 4 `sb` instructions, or 2 `sh` instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `lui`/`ori` construct a value in a register from an immediate, without accessing data memory.  They're not in any way equivalent to `lw`.  Perhaps you're thinking of `li`, which is a pseudo-instruction for `lui` and/or `ori`.  Only load instructions can access memory; immediate ALU instructions take data from the instruction itself but that doesn't really count.

---

**MIPS provides pairs of instructions for loading/storing the left and right parts of an unaligned word.  The stores are `SWL` (left) and `SWR` (store word right).**

Their effect depends on the endian mode of your MIPS (it support big and little endian).  [MARS simulates a MIPS in little-endian mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533430/is-mars-mips-simulator-big-or-little-endian)

In little-endian mode, `SWL $t1, buf` stores the high byte of $t1 to the first byte of `buf`, for an aligned `buf`.

In little-endian mode, **on an address that *is* aligned (like `sw` requires<sup>1</sup>), SWR acts like SW, storing all 4 bytes.**

These instructions are interesting because they can modify 1 to 4 bytes in a word.  Including 3 bytes, which you can't do with one `sb` (byte) or `sh` (half-word).

---

http://db.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall02/cps104/homework/lwswlr.html explains how to use the SPARC instructions of the same name.  I think MIPS (in big-endian mode) would be the same, and MIPS in little-endian mode like MARS simulates is like that but reversed.

So in big-endian mode, I think `swl` is equivalent to `sw` for aligned addresses, but I haven't tested.

---

Footnote 1:
[MIPS32R6 removed LWL/R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64_Release_6), and requires LW to support unaligned store / load.  Wikipedia doesn't mention stores for that, only loads.

See also https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Alignment: Linux MIPS has a kernel option to emulate unaligned load/store instead of delivering SIGBUS on unaligned LW or SW.